# Android API v28, KeyEvent 82 not responding?

Tags: android, keyevent

This is throwing me off a little bit. I am working on a small plugin for Home Assistant that works as a remote for my Android TV box (Nvidia SheildTV). I am sending commands via adb. I am attempting to send the command for MENU, which should be KeyEvent 82. However, nothing happens when I send it. I can send other commands and they respond as expected, but the menu event will never trigger on KeyEvent 82 as it should. Is there a new command or is there a way this is being blocked by the system somehow? If so, is there a way to enable it?

Comment: What makes you think anyone is listening for the Menu KeyEvent in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean? I am trying to send the menu key via adb. It should trigger the menu but it doesn't work.

Comment: The menu button was deprecated back [in 2012](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html). What menu are you expecting to respond? Why do you believe that *any* menu is connected to that key event?

Comment: Conversely, if you are trying to replicate the behavior of some button on a physical remote, what makes you think that the remote's button maps to 82 (or, for that matter, maps to any `KeyEvent`)? For example, you might provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you *received* that remote button click in an app, and how when you logged the result, it turned out to be 82. After all, there is no requirement for a physical button on a remote to result in any form of `KeyEvent`, particularly for a proprietary remote for a particular piece of hardware. NVIDIA can do whatever NVIDIA wants.